# Challenging group by in R on multiple columns

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I have a dataframe with some baseball data, that looks like the following:

```
dput(pitchdata)
structure(list(stand = c("R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "L", "L", "L", 
"L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
"L", "L", "R", "R", "R", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "R", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "R", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "L"), zone = c(12L, 3L, 5L, 14L, 1L, 6L, 12L, 11L, 
7L, 12L, 8L, 1L, 14L, 14L, 3L, 11L, 9L, 9L, 12L, 9L, 14L, 4L, 
4L, 2L, 4L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 5L, 13L, 14L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 12L, 5L, 
6L, 11L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 13L, 11L, 1L, 14L, 13L, 1L, 7L, 7L), 
    balls = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), strikes = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L)), .Names = c("stand", "zone", "balls", "strikes"), row.names = c(NA, 
50L), class = "data.frame")

  stand zone balls strikes
1     R   12     0       1
2     R    3     0       0
3     R    5     1       1
4     R   14     0       1
5     R    1     0       0
6     L    6     3       2
```

The whole pitchdata table has ~1M rows, and I would like to compute counts and percentages for these columns of data. My data has 14 options for zones (1:14), 4 for balls (0:3), 3 for strikes (0:2), and 2 for stand ("L", "R"). I know I can do a simple group by with:

```
pitchdata %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(stand, zone, balls, strikes) %>%
  dplyr::summarise( freq = n() )
```

**however**, I would also like to create a grouped-by group that includes stand == "All" (both "L" and "R"), which I can then create by excluding stand in the group by with:

```
pitchdata %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(zone, balls, strikes) %>%
  dplyr::summarise( freq = n() )
```

**however** again, I would also like to group by that includes balls == "All" (0, 1, 2, 3), which I can create by with:

```
pitchdata %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(zone, stand, strikes) %>%
  dplyr::summarise( freq = n() )
```

however the three group by's above all miss the group with stand == "All" and balls == "All", so I can then do:

```
pitchdata %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(zone, strikes) %>%
  dplyr::summarise( freq = n() )
```

... this approach becomes repetitive. To account for strikes == "All", I need to do an additional two group bys:

```
pitchdata %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(zone, stand, balls) %>%
  dplyr::summarise( freq = n() ) 

pitchdata %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(zone, balls) %>%
  dplyr::summarise( freq = n() )
```

If this were the end of it, it would be okay, however an additional column I would like is **the total for each group across all of the 14 zones**. For example, for the group stand == "R" & balls == "0" & strikes == "1", I would like the sum of the frequencies for this group across all of the 14 zones. This can be done verbosely if I do an additional 7 group bys (one for each of the previous 7 group bys), for each one excluding zone as a grouped variable.

In total, I have to perform 14 group bys to achieve my desired result. To reiterate, my desired result is a dataframe with 14 (zones) * 20 (pitch count groups) * 3 (lefty, righty, all groups) = 840 rows. Each row should look like this:

```
zone  stand  balls  strikes  freq  all_zone_freq  
  12    "R"     0         1   324           1824
```

where, in this example, the 324 is the count for zone 12, stand R, balls 0, and strikes 1, and 1824 is the count for stand R, balls 0, strikes 1 (across all 14 zones).

How can I do this without 14 group bys? And please let me know if I can explain the Q better!

EDIT: the 20 pitch-count groups are: 
  0,0  0,1  0,2  1,0  1,1  1,2  2,0  2,1  2,2  3,0  3,1  3,2  0-balls, 1-ball, 2-balls, 3-balls, 0-strikes, 1-strike, 2-strikes, all-counts.

Answer (score 0):

You should do:

1 - Create a expand.grid()

```
expand <- pitchdata %>%
expand(zone = zone, stand = stand, balls = balls, strike = strike)
```

2 - Create in pitchdata a variable for count:

```
pitchdata <- pitchdata %>% mutate(count = 1)
```

3 - Merge the dataframes:

```
join <- left_join(expand,pitchdata, by = c(zone = "zone", stand = "stand",
                                             balls = "balls", strike = "strike))
```

4 - Count the observations:

```
count <- join %>% 
  group_by(zone, stand, balls, strike) %>% 
  summarise(count = sum(count))
```

5 - I believe it should work with a few modifications (or maybe none)